# display an image from json data using AFNetworking3 objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios10, afnetworking-3

I want to display an image from json data using AFNetworking3 objective c,
I used this code but it crashes!

this is my son link:
mkssab.com/api/index

this is my code:

NSDictionary *images = data[@"images"];

cell.adPic.image=[images valueForKey:@"photo"];

message of crash:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000001a5cc0'

Comment: Guess from the error message (and verified with your JSON) `[images valueForKey:@"photo"]` is not a `UIImage` object, it's a `NSArray` one. Also, you may want to DOWNLOAD the UIImage, which isn't the case here. So either by constructing the URL (seems just to be a image name) and calling `setImageWithURL:`.

Comment: @Larme can you help me with code example plz ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

}

NSString *urlString = @"https://mkssab.com/uploads/file-1499084006-595a34e63e885.PNG";// example:http://mkssab.com/somePic.jpg
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if (data) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
}
```

but `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` will block the main thread,maybe you can try to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
like this:

```
[cell.adPic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mkssab.com/somePic.jpg"]
```

Comment: @ibtdiibtdi [images valueForKey:@"photo"]; is not valid url

Comment: sorry, I don't understand can you explain?

Comment: @ibtdiibtdi check you image url

Comment: @ibtdiibtd I am update my answer,I am sure can working,maybe you should  append "https:// " to you imageURL